# How to set border-radius conditionally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap's `nav-tabs`. I would like to make all the corners of `tab-content`rounded except when the first tab is selected.

So basically in this case when the first `<li>` has active class then `.tab-content`'s `border-top-left-radius` should be nothing.

I am not sure how do i conditionally set the styles just for 1st tab?

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/rv12dLub/5/)

**Update 1**

Ok i got it working by setting styles on individual `tab-pane`

```
.tab-pane:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241,241);        
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.0px;
    border-color: #ADADAD;
    padding: 20px;  
}

.tab-pane:first-child{
    background-color: rgb(241, 241,241);  
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;          
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.0px;
    border-color: #ADADAD;
    padding: 20px;  
}
```

i was wondering if i can avoid repetition and combine?

new [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/rv12dLub/10/)

Comment: I don't think you you can do this without some JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by either using JavaScript or moving the `tab-content` inside of the `<ul>` .nav

### [Your updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv12dLub/6/)

After you move the content inside the nav, you can  add this

```
.tab-content {
    clear: both;
}

li:nth-of-type(1).active ~ .tab-content {
  border-top-left-radius: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try moving the styles from .tab-content down into .tab-pane and then you can use child selectors for each .tab-pane.

```css
.tab-pane {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241,241);        
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.0px;
    border-color: #ADADAD;
    padding: 20px;
}
.tab-pane.active:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: i like the idea but it didnt not work here is updated jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/rv12dLub/8/

Comment: yeah, I realized it afterwards. adjusting this style with get you closer
    `.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
        color: #555555;
        cursor: default;
        background-color: rgb(241, 241,241);
        border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-color:rgb(241, 241,241);
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
    }`

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so I can't comment or upvote yet.  I'll respond to update 1 here. I think you can avoid repetition by removing the not selector and just overriding with the :first-child. So declare padding once only. Not sure what else you're doing for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally i got it working

```
.tab-pane {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241,241);        
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.0px;
    border-color: #ADADAD;
    padding: 20px;  
}

.tab-pane:first-child{    
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

here is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/rv12dLub/11/)

Comment: Ah, yep, that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this,
apply

ul#main-nav li:first-child.active{

border-top-left-radius:0;

border-bottom-left-radius:0;

}

alternatively:

ul#main-nav li:first-child.active{

border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;

}

Comment: That adjusts the menu item, OP asked to change the content border radius

Comment: Ya he can just put the class name after the li to select the tab-content class as well. thats as easy as it get.. like so


 ul#main-nav li:first-child.active .tab-content{

border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;

}

first-child and nth-child can be used in any context, you just have to use it as your html structure demands.

Comment: Simple things like this will never need an ounce of javascript. full-stop